# Running an keyword on Robotframework throw an error: ValueError: Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x106cc5b50>

Tags: python, robotframework

When I try to launch an app from robotframework using appium

I got the following error

```
ValueError: Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x106cc5b50>, but it must be an int, float or None.
```

This never happen. I do not know the reason why, all I did is just trying a simple open app keyword from robotframework appium library

pip list

```
Package                        Version
------------------------------ --------
Appium-Python-Client           1.3.0
astor                          0.8.1
async-generator                1.10
attrs                          23.1.0
beautifulsoup4                 4.9.1
certifi                        2023.5.7
chardet                        3.0.4
charset-normalizer             2.0.12
decorator                      5.1.1
docutils                       0.18.1
exceptiongroup                 1.1.1
h11                            0.14.0
idna                           2.10
kitchen                        1.2.6
lxml                           4.5.2
outcome                        1.2.0
pip                            22.0.4
PySocks                        1.7.1
PyYAML                         6.0
requests                       2.30.0
robotframework                 5.0
robotframework-appiumlibrary   1.6.3
robotframework-pabot           2.5.4
robotframework-pythonlibcore   4.1.2
robotframework-requests        0.9.2
robotframework-seleniumlibrary 6.1.0
robotframework-stacktrace      0.4.1
selenium                       3.141.0
setuptools                     60.10.0
six                            1.16.0
sniffio                        1.3.0
sortedcontainers               2.4.0
soupsieve                      2.0.1
strutil                        0.2.1
tk                             0.1.0
trio                           0.22.0
trio-websocket                 0.10.2
urllib3                        2.0.2
wheel                          0.37.1
wsproto                        1.2.0
```

Pip3 list

```
Package                        Version
------------------------------ --------
Appium-Python-Client           1.3.0
astor                          0.8.1
async-generator                1.10
attrs                          23.1.0
beautifulsoup4                 4.9.1
certifi                        2023.5.7
chardet                        3.0.4
charset-normalizer             2.0.12
decorator                      5.1.1
docutils                       0.18.1
exceptiongroup                 1.1.1
h11                            0.14.0
idna                           2.10
kitchen                        1.2.6
lxml                           4.5.2
outcome                        1.2.0
pip                            22.0.4
PySocks                        1.7.1
PyYAML                         6.0
requests                       2.30.0
robotframework                 5.0
robotframework-appiumlibrary   1.6.3
robotframework-pabot           2.5.4
robotframework-pythonlibcore   4.1.2
robotframework-requests        0.9.2
robotframework-seleniumlibrary 6.1.0
robotframework-stacktrace      0.4.1
selenium                       3.141.0
setuptools                     60.10.0
six                            1.16.0
sniffio                        1.3.0
sortedcontainers               2.4.0
soupsieve                      2.0.1
strutil                        0.2.1
tk                             0.1.0
trio                           0.22.0
trio-websocket                 0.10.2
urllib3                        2.0.2
wheel                          0.37.1
wsproto                        1.2.0
```

My python version

```
Python 3.9.12
```

**The Appium is not running when I check the log, which could be the issue?**

My sample app

```
*** Settings ***

#  Default Library
Library         AppiumLibrary
Library         BuiltIn

*** Variables ***
${path}         /Users/jj/Downloads/sample.apk


*** Test Cases ***

Install the app
    Open Application    http://localhost:4723/wd/hub    alias=Myapp1    platformName=iOS    platformVersion=7.0 deviceName='iPhone Simulator'   app=${path}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the python package **selenium==4.9.0** ; on macOS

```
ValueError: Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x103094d40>, but it must be an int, float or None.
```

So, as a temporary troubleshooting, I downgraded it to 4.8.0 like this

```
pip install --force-reinstall -v "selenium==4.8.0"
```

If that solves your problem, please consider stabilizing/fixing your version in the **requirements.txt**:

```
...
selenium==4.8.0
...
```

Then remove your venv and reinstall it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation running some tests in Azure DevOps pipeline. The situation was caused by the urllib3 dependency, and when I downgraded the library to version lower than 2.0.0 Open Application functioned properly in my pipeline

Apparently there was a major change with the default timeout for the urllib3 2.0.0 that causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by downgrade my selenium version on my mac

do not know why like that, seem like there is some bug

My working version

```
Package                      Version
---------------------------- --------
Appium-Python-Client         2.9.0
astor                        0.8.1
async-generator              1.10
attrs                        23.1.0
beautifulsoup4               4.9.1
certifi                      2023.5.7
cffi                         1.15.1
chardet                      3.0.4
charset-normalizer           2.0.12
cryptography                 40.0.2
decorator                    5.1.1
docutils                     0.18.1
exceptiongroup               1.1.1
h11                          0.14.0
idna                         2.10
kitchen                      1.2.6
lxml                         4.5.2
outcome                      1.2.0
pip                          22.0.4
pycparser                    2.21
pyOpenSSL                    23.1.1
PySocks                      1.7.1
PyYAML                       6.0
requests                     2.30.0
robotframework               6.0.2
robotframework-appiumlibrary 1.6
selenium                     4.1.2
setuptools                   60.10.0
six                          1.16.0
sniffio                      1.3.0
sortedcontainers             2.4.0
soupsieve                    2.0.1
strutil                      0.2.1
tk                           0.1.0
trio                         0.22.0
trio-websocket               0.10.2
urllib3                      1.26.15
urllib3-secure-extra         0.1.0
wheel                        0.37.1
wsproto                      1.2.0
```